# How would I write code that gets me the output of: 25 and 100

Tags: python

I need to write a code that allows the output to be this :

```
25
100
```

This is the code I have, but can't seem to get the correct output:

```
a = 5**2
b = 10^10
```

When I write this code out: `print("a \n b")` Output:

```
a
b
```

How would I get it where the 2 variables print out 25 and 100 instead of a and b?

Comment: please take a look at [Print()](https://realpython.com/python-print/) function details, try to figure out with this help

Comment: [You can format the string using these options](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) then print using print(str).

Comment: `print(a)` `print(b)` without `" "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a more recent Python 3 version (Higher than 3.6 I guess) you may use the f strings to get the result

```
print(f"{a} '\n {b}")
```

Here is its definition from PEP-498:

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value. In Python source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with 'f', which contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with their values.

Otherwise, there are numerous ways to get the result, such as

```
print(a, '\n', b)
print('{} \n {}'.format(a, b))
```

and many others.

Comment: Thank you Henry! I was missing the F-string which I needed!

Comment: My pleasure @Adam32